# vue.js Bootstrap Modal Data Bind Fails

Tags: vue.js

I'm having some issues with binding data within a Bootstrap modal element. If I move everything in the `modal-body` class outside the modal container it works fine, however, vue.js doesn't pick up the bindings within the modal.

Not sure if this has something to do with the modal styles (`display: none;` before it's opened) or conflicting scripts. The modal code looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div v-if="loading" class="text-center">

          <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading">

        </div>
        <div v-else>

          <div v-if="plugins.length > 0" class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(index, plugin) in wpplugins">
              <h5 class="list-group-item-heading"><strong>{{ plugin.name }}</strong> by {{ plugin.author }}</h5>
              <p class="list-group-item-text"><small>{{ plugin.desc }}</small></p>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This ends up just outputting the image and the syntax:

[How it appears in the modal when open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPGu1.png)

Comment: is your modal within the element that your Vue app is bound to?

Comment: Either what Jeff asked, or I would  guess that Bootstrap somehow duplicates or moves the modal body elements in a way that removes the Vue bindings.

Comment: I have use vue with external resources, including bootstrap, and I'd haven't any problem like that. If you still think that could be the bootstrap js library, try with [vue-strap](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap). Anyway what I see there, is that Vue isn't present in your app, because is ignoring the bindings, the `v-if` and everything related with Vue

Comment: @Jeff That was it! I was really overthinking it. Thanks!

Comment: @ractoon no problem, glad it worked! I put an answer so future viewers may be helped by the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your modal code is within the element that Vue is bound to